# Permissions problems with proc_open

Tags: php, permissions

I'm having permissions problems when running the following PHP script **as root**:

```php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$ph = proc_open('whoami', [['pipe','r'],['pipe','w'],['file','/tmp/foo.bar', 'w']], $fds);
if ($ph) {
    echo 'command output: ' . stream_get_contents($fds[1]);
    proc_close($ph);
} else {
    echo 'proc_open failed' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The script itself runs fine if `/tmp/foo.bar` doesn't exist, or is owned by root. But if ownership is changed to another user, `proc_open` will fail regardless of permissions on the file.

SELinux is disabled, and we are not using ACLs. I'm using PHP 7.4.33 (I know it's old and unsupported, but it's a requirement for FreePBX) on Alma Linux 9.1.

Output:

```
$ ./test.php
command output: root
$ ls -lah /tmp/
total 12K
drwxrwxrwt. 18 root     root     4.0K Dec 14 16:57 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root     root     4.0K Dec 14 16:48 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root        0 Dec 14 16:57 foo.bar
$ chown admin /tmp/foo.bar
$ ./test.php
proc_open failed
$ chmod 777 /tmp/foo.bar
$ ./test.php
proc_open failed
$ ls -lah /tmp/
total 12K
drwxrwxrwt. 18 root     root     4.0K Dec 14 16:57 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root     root     4.0K Dec 14 16:48 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 admin    root        0 Dec 14 16:57 foo.bar
$ tail -2 /var/log/php.log
[14-Dec-2022 16:57:17 America/Toronto] PHP Warning:  proc_open(/tmp/foo.bar): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /test.php on line 3
[14-Dec-2022 16:57:28 America/Toronto] PHP Warning:  proc_open(/tmp/foo.bar): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /test.php on line 3
```

Even disregarding the fact that I'm root, group permissions should allow me full access to the file. So what's going on?

Comment: PHP 7.4.33 is not really old. most likely its a supported version in your linux distribution. And my guess is that `'w'` for the file mode should be replaced with `'a'`.

Comment: The actual FreePBX code that I've reduced here is using append mode, with the same result. (I didn't realize 7.4 was still getting security updates until last month!)

Comment: just seeing, error only after chown, correct? this is /tmp, it has setuid or similar. only the owner has access to the file. check with your system administration manual, my wording is likely imprecise. this is as traditional /tmp is shared on the system across all users but they should not leak data. use [`tmpfile(php)`](https://php.net/tmpfile) to have a file your own, if that is what you're looking for. IIRC proc_open also accepts stream handles.

Comment: This problem seems to be specific to the `/tmp` directory, probably related to its use of the sticky bit. If I change the script to put the file in my home directory, it works fine.

Comment: Yup that's the problem. Found this answer on [unix.se]: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503169/73390

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the permissions on the `/tmp` directory. When PHP tries to open the file for writing, it gets the `EACCES` error. From the documentation of `open(2)`:

`EACCES`
Where O_CREAT is specified, the protected_fifos or protected_regular sysctl is enabled, the file already exists and is a FIFO or regular file, the owner  of  the file  is  neither  the current user nor the owner of the containing directory, and the containing directory is both world- or group-writable and sticky.  For details, see the descriptions of `/proc/sys/fs/protected_fifos` and `/proc/sys/fs/protected_regular` in `proc(5)`.

`/tmp` has the sticky bit set so that anyone can create files there, but users can only delete their own files. Although `root` can bypass this deletion restriction, it can't bypass the above check in `open()`.

Comment: Thanks; I'm migrating our systems from RHEL 6 to 9, so this is new stuff for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I tried this in a different directory than `/tmp`, as suggested in comments, and it worked as expected. Using that to hone my search terms I was able pretty quickly to find  [this U&L answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503169/73390). Beginning with kernel 4.19 the `fs.protected_regular` kernel parameter was made available. This parameter:

> Disallows open of FIFOs or regular files not owned by the user in world writable sticky directories, unless the owner is the same as that of the directory or the file is opened without the O_CREAT flag. The purpose is to make data spoofing attacks harder.

Apparently it's enabled by default. So because `/tmp` is world-writable and sticky, I can't touch files that aren't mine – even if I'm root. For the record, if I have to disable this feature:

```bash
sysctl fs.protected_regular=0
echo 'fs.protected_regular=0' > /etc/sysctl.d/90-writabletemp.conf
```

But I'll be better off trying to work around it in the code somehow.

Comment: I do know nothing about the inards of freepbx, but often for an application the temporary directory can be configured so that it is not the system one, but one for the application (and the user executing the app). XDG comes to mind, check if freepbx supports this or different configuration for the TEMPorary files. And additionally if you're root, can't you become the other user without disabling the protection?

Comment: It is hard coded in the code to `/tmp` rather than using `mktemp()` or something; and I can sudo but it's a pain to remember. Since the docs say it will work if "the [file] owner is the same as that of the directory" I should be able to change to root ownership and set 777 perms and that way the FreePBX user will be able to work with it as well.